# How to install Magento Cloud CLI?

Tags: magento2, cli, magento2-cloud

I'm running a Magento Commerce Cloud in my new machine and I need to install the Magento Cloud CLI.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - You can install it using this command below.

```
curl -sS https://accounts.magento.cloud/cli/installer | php
```

2 - Then add the Magento Cloud CLI to the bash profile.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.magento-cloud/bin
```

3 - And reload the bash.

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

4- To check if it worked run:

```
magento-cloud
```

Reference: [Magento Cloud CLI reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html)

Comment: i am getting following error when run first command "Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'sS'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -sS https://accounts.magento.cloud/cli/installer | php
+      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand"

Comment: Check your local PHP, I just test it and it's working normally @AlamZaib

Comment: I have xampp server having php 7.4

Answer (score 0):

> **To Install the magento-cloud CLI**

**Step-1** : Go to **/var/www/html** folder and create new folder **magentocloud**. After go into magentocloud folder.

```
  cd /var/www/html/

  mkdir magentocloud

  cd magentocloud/
```

**Step-2** : Install the magento-cloud CLI.

```
  curl -sS https://accounts.magento.cloud/cli/installer | php
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  username@linux-pc:/var/www/html/magentocloud$ curl -sS https://accounts.magento.cloud/cli/installer | php
  Magento Cloud CLI installer

  Environment check
    [*] The "json" PHP extension is installed.
    [*] The "phar" PHP extension is installed.
    [*] Git is installed.
    [*] The "openssl" PHP extension is installed.
    [*] The "pcre" PHP extension is installed.
    [*] One or both of the "mbstring" or "iconv" PHP extensions is installed.
    [*] The "curl" PHP extension is installed.
    [*] The "pcntl" and "posix" extensions are installed.
    [*] The "allow_url_fopen" setting is on.
    [*] The "apc.enable_cli" setting is off.

  Download
    Finding the latest version... done
    Downloading version 1.38.1... done
    Checking file integrity... done
    Checking that the file is a valid Phar... done

  Install
    Making the Phar executable... done
    Moving the Phar to your home directory... done
    Executable location: /home/username/.magento-cloud/bin/magento-cloud

  Running self:install command...

  Copying resource files... done

  Installing credential helper... done

  Setting up autocompletion... done

  Selected shell configuration file: ~/.bashrc

  Do you want to update the file automatically? [Y/n] y

  Configuration file updated successfully: ~/.bashrc

  To use the Magento Cloud CLI, run:
      source ~/.bashrc # (make sure your shell does this by default)
      magento-cloud
```

**Step-3** : Add **magento-cloud** CLI to the bash profile

```
  export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.magento-cloud/bin
```

**Step-4** : Reload the updated bash profile.

```
  . ~/.bash_profile
```

After running the Step-2 command we get the profile name. Used that name.

```
  . ~/.bashrc
```

**Step-5** : To initiate the CLI, call magento-cloud and enter your Cloud account credentials when prompted.

```
  magento-cloud
```

**OutPut:**

```
  username@linux-pc:/var/www/html/magentocloud$ magento-cloud
  Welcome to Magento Cloud!

  Loading projects...
  Authentication is required.

  Log in via a browser? [Y/n] y

  Opened URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000
  Please use the browser to log in.

  Help:
    Leave this command running during login.
    If you need to quit, use Ctrl+C.

  Opening in existing browser session.
  libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
  Login information received. Verifying...
  You are logged in.

  Generating SSH certificate...
  A new SSH certificate has been generated.
  It will be automatically refreshed when necessary.
  Do you want to create an SSH configuration file automatically? [Y/n] y
  Configuration file created successfully: /home/username/.ssh/config

  Username: cloud-username cloud-username
  Email address: cloud.username@gmail.com
  Your projects are:
  +---------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
  | ID            | Title            | URL                                                 |
  +---------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
  | XXXXXXXXXXXXX | Project Name 1   | https://XXXXXX.magento.cloud/projects/XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
  | XXXXXXXXXXXXX | Project Name 2   | https://XXXXXX.magento.cloud/projects/XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
  +---------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+

  Get a project by running: magento-cloud get [id]
  List a project's environments by running: magento-cloud environments -p [id]

  You are logged in as cloud-username (cloud.username@gmail.com)

  To view all commands, run: magento-cloud list
```

[image]

**You must be login into browser with magento-cloud account.**

**Step-6** : Verify the **magento-cloud** command is in your path. The following example lists the available commands.

```
  magento-cloud list
```

**OutPUT:**

```
username@linux-pc:/var/www/html/magentocloud$ magento-cloud list
Magento Cloud CLI 1.38.1

Global options:
  --help           -h Display this help message
  --quiet          -q Do not output any message
  --verbose        -v|vv|vvv Increase the verbosity of messages
  --version        -V Display this application version
  --yes            -y Answer "yes" to any yes/no questions; disable interaction
  --no             -n Answer "no" to any yes/no questions; disable interaction

Available commands:
  clear-cache (clearcache, cc)                                  Clear the CLI cache
  decode                                                        Decode an encoded string such as MAGENTO_CLOUD_VARIABLES
  docs                                                          Open the online documentation
  help                                                          Displays help for a command
  list                                                          Lists commands
  multi                                                         Execute a command on multiple projects
  web                                                           Open the Web UI
activity
  activity:cancel                                               Cancel an activity
  activity:get                                                  View detailed information on a single activity
  activity:list (activities, act)                               Get a list of activities for an environment or project
  activity:log                                                  Display the log for an activity
app
  app:config-get                                                View the configuration of an app
  app:list (apps)                                               List apps in the project
auth
  auth:api-token-login                                          Log in to Magento Cloud using an API token
  auth:browser-login (login)                                    Log in to Magento Cloud via a browser
  auth:info                                                     Display your account information
  auth:logout (logout)                                          Log out of Magento Cloud
backup
blackfire
  blackfire:setup                                               Setup Blackfire.io integration for the project
certificate
  certificate:add                                               Add an SSL certificate to the project
  certificate:delete                                            Delete a certificate from the project
  certificate:get                                               View a certificate
  certificate:list (certificates, certs)                        List project certificates
commit
  commit:get                                                    Show commit details
  commit:list (commits)                                         List commits
db
  db:dump                                                       Create a local dump of the remote database
  db:size                                                       Estimate the disk usage of a database
  db:sql (sql)                                                  Run SQL on the remote database
domain
  domain:add                                                    Add a new domain to the project
  domain:delete                                                 Delete a domain from the project
  domain:get                                                    Show detailed information for a domain
  domain:list (domains)                                         Get a list of all domains
  domain:update                                                 Update a domain
environment
  environment:activate                                          Activate an environment
  environment:branch (branch)                                   Branch an environment
  environment:checkout (checkout)                               Check out an environment
  environment:delete (environment:deactivate)                   Delete an environment
  environment:http-access (httpaccess)                          Update HTTP access settings for an environment
  environment:info                                              Read or set properties for an environment
  environment:init                                              Initialize an environment from a public Git repository
  environment:list (environments, env)                          Get a list of environments
  environment:logs (log)                                        Read an environment's logs
  environment:merge (merge)                                     Merge an environment
  environment:push (push)                                       Push code to an environment
  environment:redeploy (redeploy)                               Redeploy an environment
  environment:relationships (relationships)                     Show an environment's relationships
  environment:scp (scp)                                         Copy files to and from current environment using scp
  environment:ssh (ssh)                                         SSH to the current environment
  environment:synchronize (sync)                                Synchronize an environment's code and/or data from its parent
  environment:url (url)                                         Get the public URLs of an environment
  environment:xdebug (xdebug)                                   Open a tunnel to Xdebug on the environment
i
integration
  integration:activity:get                                      View detailed information on a single integration activity
  integration:activity:list (i:act)                             Get a list of activities for an integration
  integration:activity:log                                      Display the log for an integration activity
  integration:add                                               Add an integration to the project
  integration:delete                                            Delete an integration from a project
  integration:get                                               View details of an integration
  integration:list (integrations)                               View a list of project integration(s)
  integration:update                                            Update an integration
  integration:validate                                          Validate an existing integration
local
  local:build (build)                                           Build the current project locally
  local:dir (dir)                                               Find the local project root
mount
  mount:download                                                Download files from a mount, using rsync
  mount:list (mounts)                                           Get a list of mounts
  mount:size                                                    Check the disk usage of mounts
  mount:upload                                                  Upload files to a mount, using rsync
project
  project:clear-build-cache                                     Clear a project's build cache
  project:get (get)                                             Clone a project locally
  project:info                                                  Read or set properties for a project
  project:list (projects, pro)                                  Get a list of all active projects
  project:set-remote                                            Set the remote project for the current Git repository
repo
  repo:cat                                                      Read a file in the project repository
  repo:ls                                                       List files in the project repository
route
  route:get                                                     View detailed information about a route
  route:list (routes)                                           List all routes for an environment
self
  self:install                                                  Install or update CLI configuration files
  self:update (self-update)                                     Update the CLI to the latest version
service
  service:list (services)                                       List services in the project
  service:mongo:dump (mongodump)                                Create a binary archive dump of data from MongoDB
  service:mongo:export (mongoexport)                            Export data from MongoDB
  service:mongo:restore (mongorestore)                          Restore a binary archive dump of data into MongoDB
  service:mongo:shell (mongo)                                   Use the MongoDB shell
  service:redis-cli (redis)                                     Access the Redis CLI
snapshot
  snapshot:create (backup)                                      Make a snapshot of an environment
  snapshot:list (snapshots)                                     List available snapshots of an environment
ssh-cert
  ssh-cert:load                                                 Generate an SSH certificate
ssh-key
  ssh-key:add                                                   Add a new SSH key
  ssh-key:delete                                                Delete an SSH key
  ssh-key:list (ssh-keys)                                       Get a list of SSH keys in your account
tunnel
  tunnel:close                                                  Close SSH tunnels
  tunnel:info                                                   View relationship info for SSH tunnels
  tunnel:list (tunnels)                                         List SSH tunnels
  tunnel:open                                                   Open SSH tunnels to an app's relationships
  tunnel:single                                                 Open a single SSH tunnel to an app relationship
user
  user:add                                                      Add a user to the project
  user:delete                                                   Delete a user from the project
  user:get                                                      View a user's role(s)
  user:list (users)                                             List project users
  user:update                                                   Update user role(s) on a project
variable
  variable:create                                               Create a variable
  variable:delete                                               Delete a variable
  variable:get (vget)                                           View a variable
  variable:list (variables, var)                                List variables
  variable:update                                               Update a variable
worker
  worker:list (workers)                                         Get a list of all deployed workers
```

**Reference Link** : https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html

***Note: Create your local machine SSH key and add into your [magento cloud account](https://accounts.magento.cloud/user). Before you start installing Magento Cloud CLI you must be login into browser with your cloud account***

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100 -C "cloud.username@gmail.com"
```

**Add SSH key Here**

[image]